# how to set proxy with authentication in multiple threads selenium wire chromedriver python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am creating a script to bypass captcha use auth proxies import from text file and run it in multiple threads selenium chromedriver. When I run 1 thread it still correct. However when I run multiple threads It still some chrome running correctly and some chrome do not running correctly proxy(do not import proxy). This is my code :

```
def randomf():
    path="data/Proxies.txt"
    file=open(path,'r').read()
    proxy=file.splitlines()
    proxyrandom='http://'+random.choice(list(proxy))
    proxyrandom1=proxyrandom.strip()
    print(proxyrandom1)
    options = {
        'proxy': {'http': proxyrandom1} }
    return options
def e():
    options1=randomf()

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('data/chromedriver.exe', seleniumwire_options=options1)

    driver.get('http://whoer.net')

    time.sleep(7200)


for _ in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=e, args=())
    thread.start()
```

And some captures of my issues:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1err.png

Answer (score 0):

This is not best practice in selenium

Two Factor Authentication shortly know as 2FA is an authorization mechanism where One Time Password(OTP) is generated using “Authenticator” mobile apps such as “Google Authenticator”, “Microsoft Authenticator” etc., or by SMS, e-mail to authenticate. Automating this seamlessly and consistently is a big challenge in Selenium. There are some ways to automate this process. But that will be another layer on top of our Selenium tests and not secured as well. So, you can avoid automating 2FA.

There are few options to get around 2FA checks:

Disable 2FA for certain Users in the test environment, so that you can use those user credentials in the automation.
Disable 2FA in your test environment.
Disable 2FA if you log in from certain IPs. That way we can configure our test machine IPs to avoid this.